# Asp.net dynamic table content is removed when saved in Viewstate

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, viewstate

Set content of table
...

```
ViewState["Table1"] = Table1; // When remove this line, table is seen on the page.
```

...

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is I tried to initialize ViewState not inside an event, but inside a function. As I learned ViewState must be initialized in event.